# Error with saving text line into array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aix

I'm trying to extract directory location from location.txt and save it into an array, but it's not looking good. When I execute the script,

i get this error

```
  ./test.sh: line 7: location.txt: No such file or directory bina@ajax $ ./test.sh
  ./test.sh: line 5: =/apps/IBM: No such file or directory
  ./test.sh: line 5: =/usr/home: No such file or directory
  ./test.sh: line 11: Unix_Array[0]: command not found

  ./test.sh: line 11: Unix_Array[1]: command not found
```

Here is my code

```
   #!/bin/sh

   counter=0
   while read -r line; do
       ${Unix_Array[${counter}]}=$line;
       let counter=counter+1;
   done < location.txt

   for ((i=0 ;counter > i; i++))
   do
       echo $(Unix_Array[$i])
   done
```

and the text file
location.txt

```
   /apps/IBM
   /usr/home
   /var/login
```

Can some one tell me what I did wrong? 
I may have made one stupid error that i don't know...(I'm really new in UNIX)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really want to use `bash` here or whatever `/bin/sh` is on AIX?

Comment: Your error comes from `echo $(Unix_Array[$i])` instead of `echo ${Unix_Array[$i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your first `${}` on `${Unix_Array[${counter}]}=$line;` because you just want to assign to the array, not assign **and** retrieve its value, your fixed script would be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

counter=0
while read -r line; do
   Unix_Array[${counter}]=$line;
   let counter=counter+1;
done < location.txt

for ((i=0 ;counter > i; i++))
do
     echo ${Unix_Array[$i]}
done
```

Comment: And update to `#!/bin/bash` while you're at it.  Arrays aren't supported by the default `sh` on a lot of distros.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash 4 or later, you can forgo the `while read` loop in favor of the `readarray` command:

```
readarray Unix_Array < location.txt

for line in "${Unix_Array[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```